# deploy java desktop application in netbeans

Tags: linux, visual-studio, netbeans

I create a java desktop application in Netbeans and now I want to deploy to work as software in Linux but I am not very familiar with neat beans I used visual studio and mono to build  applications for both Windows and Linux and both of them create your application in bin/release directory and  now I want to know what is equivalent to visual studio/mono release in Netbeans.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project folder. Inside that there is a folder named "dist" this contains the jar file. This is the java equivalent of .exe. You need to use that to run on linux(given that JRE is installed on Linux machine). In case of external libraies: the libraries exists in side the "lib" folder which resides inside the "dist" folder.